# Invoking a BPMN REST Endpoint in WSO2BPS and get payloads in to format xml

Tags: wso2, activiti, bpmn, wso2-business-process

I want to use BPMN Service Task and invoke a REST API.
I need to receive requests from the service ESB in format XML.

Example of request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<reqSendEvent extrSystem="rout" typeEvent="newRout" xmlns="http://magnit.ru/tanderCoreMassageData.xsd">
  <originTime>2017.08.25 15:12:00</originTime>
  <content>
    <rout>
      <name>xxxxx</name>      
    </rout>
  </content>
</reqSendEvent>
```

servicetask:

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:class="org.wso2.developerstudio.bpmn.extensions.restTask.RESTTask">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="serviceURL">
      <activiti:expression><![CDATA[http://localhost:9773/tanderBPMN/services/servicetask1]]></activiti:expression>
    </activiti:field>
    <activiti:field name="method">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[POST]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
    <activiti:field name="headers">
      <activiti:expression><![CDATA[Content-Type:text/xml]]></activiti:expression>
    </activiti:field>
    <activiti:field name="outputMappings">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

In all the examples, using JSON payloads. What do i write expression in to the outputMappings to get value from tag *//rout/name?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a simple String to hold the POST payload and map the parameter to the String.

Have you tried this?
Greg